# ag-Grid create template to a column not working- AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, ag-grid

I am populating a data table using ag-Grid. I want to create a template column. Here is my code. However, I am not able to provide the fiddle, since the grid table is not displaying in the fiddle.

JS :

```
agGrid.initialiseAgGridWithAngular1(angular);

var app = angular.module('myApp', ['agGrid']);
app.controller('myController', function($scope) {
 var columnDefs = [{
  headerName: "<input type=checkbox>",
  field: "Select",
  width: 120,
  cellRenderer: function(params) {
  var htmlElement = document.createElement("input");
  htmlElement.type = 'checkbox';
  return htmlElement;
 }
}, {
 headerName: "Ref No",
 field: "rn",
 width: 120,
 template: '<a href="#/updateInspection" ng-bind="myDummyData.rn></a>'
}, {
 headerName: "Postal Code",
 field: "pc",
 width: 120
}, {
 headerName: "Zone Name",
 field: "zn",
 width: 120
}];

$scope.myDummyData = [{
 "rn": "HIP/12/TM-1",
 "pc": "400001",
 "zn": "Zone - 1"
}, {
 "rn": "HIP/12/TM-1",
 "pc": "400001",
 "zn": "Zone - 1"
}];

$scope.gridOptions = {
 columnDefs: columnDefs,
 rowData: $scope.myDummyData,
 enableFilter: true,
 enableColResize: true,
 enableSorting: true,
 rowHeight: 36,
 headerHeight: 36
};

 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var gridDiv = document.querySelector('#myGrid');
  new agGrid.Grid(gridDiv, $scope.gridOptions);
  $scope.gridOptions.api.setRowData($scope.myDummyData);
 });
});
```

HTML :

```
<div ng-controller="myController">
 <div id="myGrid" class="ag-fresh" ag-grid="gridOptions"></div>
</div>
```

All rows with values display, but the column one with the template is not displaying. Has it got something to do with the `ng-bind`?

I referred [this link](https://ag-grid.com/angular-grid-cell-template/index.php) as an example. Except for JSON data, I have created my own data.

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Turn On Angular Compile
Angular compiling is turned on by setting the grid options attribute angularCompileRows to true.

Comment: @Archanadid you try this?

Comment: yes i have used  in grid component, let try once on your project grid